# MSSQL Select with Count

Tags: sql-server, select

I have the following tables:

```
Table: persons
Person_Code   Ονοματεπώνυμο         Διεύθυνση                    Τηλέφωνο 
1              ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ ΕΛΕΝΗ    ΠΑΝΕΠΙΣΤΗΜΙΟΥ 125 ΑΘΗΝΑ       210-1111111 
2              ΓΕΩΡΓΙΟΥ ΝΙΚΟΛΑΟΣ     ΚΑΛΟΚΑΙΡΙΝΟΥ 180 ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟ     2810-992222 
3              ΑΝΤΩΝΙΟΥ ΜΙΧΑΗΛ       ΚΟΥΝΤΟΥΡΙΩΤΗ 2 ΠΑΤΡΑ          211-000222


Table: Operations
Person_Code  Κωδ_Μετοχής  Ημερομηνία    Ώρα    Είδος   Ποσότητα   Τιμή 
1             ΕΛΤΚ         2013-07-15    14:15  ΑΓΟΡΑ   100        14.30 
2             ΑΛΚΑΤ        2013-07-08    09:20  ΑΓΟΡΑ   1250       19.02  
3             ΕΛΤΚ         2013-08-14    10:30  ΠΩΛΗΣΗ  325        16.30 
1             ΑΑΑΚ         2013-09-01    11:15  ΠΩΛΗΣΗ  528        4.30
```

I want to select all the columns From the first table (`persons`) PLUS to count `the total Person_Code` from the table `operations` for each person.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT t1.onomateponimo,t1.dieuthunsh,t1.tilefono, COUNT(t2.Person_Code) 
FROM persons as t1
INNER JOIN operations as t2
    ON t1.Person_Code = t2.Person_Code
ORDER BY t1.onomateponimo ASC;
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (which I may not have), I think you need a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT t1.onomateponimo,t1.dieuthunsh,t1.tilefono, COUNT(t2.Person_Code) 
FROM persons as t1
INNER JOIN operations as t2
    ON t1.Person_Code = t2.Person_Code
GROUP BY t1.onomateponimo, t1.dieuthunsh, t1.tilefono
ORDER BY t1.onomateponimo ASC;
```

If that's not correct, why not add the expected output to your question?

Comment: Hello it worked. But can you explain me why it needs 3 column in the group by and not just one?

Comment: Glad it's the right answer. The GROUP BY needs to include all the columns that aren't part of the math operator (the COUNT, in this case - and you can have more than one math operator in a query, too). There's a more detailed explanation here: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/HQV8310312-Definition,-Use-of-Group-by-and-Having-Clause.html - If it worked for you, please consider ticking it as "accepted".

Comment: But i have seen many other examples where it uses the MSSSQL Functions like SUM,COUNT etc and they are only apply group by in one column. Well a bit confused

Comment: @user3393046 Yes, you can group by just one column but only if you're selecting one additional column. In your case you're trying to select multiple columns, so you have to group by multiple columns too.

Comment: Thank you boss! I understand everything :)

Answer (score 0):

An other SELECT statement can be the following one

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t1.onomateponimo,t1.dieuthunsh,t1.tilefono 
    FROM persons as t1
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t2.Person_Code, COUNT(t2.Person_Code) 
    FROM operations as t2
    GROUP BY t2.Person_Code
) as t2 ON t1.Person_Code = t2.Person_Code
ORDER BY t1.onomateponimo ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Matt thrower is correct. You need a Group BY Clause.

SELECT P.onomateponimo,P.dieuthunsh,P.tilefono, COUNT(O.Person_Code) 
FROM persons as P
INNER JOIN operations as O
    ON P.Person_Code = O.Person_Code
GROUP BY P.onomateponimo, P.dieuthunsh, P.tilefono

And you can add order by clause if you need the data in ordered manner.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to count people who don't have operation associated, you can query

```
SELECT t1.onomateponimo,t1.dieuthunsh,t1.tilefono, `
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM operations AS t2
    WHERE t1.Person_Code = t2.Person_Code
)
FROM persons as t1
ORDER BY t1.onomateponimo ASC;
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.onomateponimo,t1.dieuthunsh,t1.tilefono, COUNT(t2.Person_Code) 
FROM persons as t1
LEFT JOIN operations as t2
    ON t1.Person_Code = t2.Person_Code
GROUP BY t1.onomateponimo, t1.dieuthunsh, t1.tilefono
ORDER BY t1.onomateponimo ASC;
```

As I tested, 1st query is generally faster than seconds query when data volume is small.

Comment: It won't, because it is fundamentally different to a) the accepted answer, and b) the original query.

Comment: Are you talking about `INNER JOIN`?